# Use laptop as a second monitor

Tags: networking, display, monitor

I've spent far too much time Googling this and haven't been able to find anything.

I have a laptop and tower both running Ubuntu. I want to be able to use the laptop as a 2nd display to extend the tower's desktop.

The end goal being to have the tower showing Netlfix on 1 screen and a game on the laptop screen.

Is this do-able?

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured this out in a very simple way.

I connected a 2nd HDMI cable from the tower to the 2nd HDMI port on the screen. Ubuntu recognises the extra connection as a 2nd screen and extends the desktop.

Remoting in with TeamViewer then gives me the option to switch between 2 monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Why, yes, it is! Virtual KVM apps are what you need. [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) is $29 and works on  all three major OS; [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) ([source](https://github.com/brahma-dev/synergy-stable-builds)) and [x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html) with a [VNC server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) are open source.