# How to use windows laptop as second monitor for ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, windows-10

I have an old windows 10 laptop, I want to use it as a second monitor for my ubuntu (20.04 LTS) laptop. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps proxy x server could accomplish what you want: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136942/extend-desktop-to-monitor-over-lan
https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/Xdmx.1.xhtml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use windows laptop as second screen to Ubuntu laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456062/use-windows-laptop-as-second-screen-to-ubuntu-laptop)  Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1079015